# Adding numbers in a list. Python

Tags: python

How do I create a function that adds all the numbers in a given list? In Python.
Something like this:

```
list = [8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7]

def sum(list):
    ???
```

Comment: you can just use `sum(list)`. BTW, don't call your variables `list` - you'll override standard data structure

Comment: Sorry but I downvoted, since you've not even tried the line of code you posted…

Comment: lol @septi really he did posted a code that didnt try!

Comment: @septi_ Well, that code wouldn't have run. He obviously doesn't know that there already is such a function - as soon as he defined it himself, he overrode it...

Comment: I of course meant "trying `sum` in the interpreter" or _at_ _least_ a google search with "python sum numbers", not his attempt of function definition/sketch ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To answer strictly what you asked:

```
# notice how I've named it 'lst' not 'list'—'list' is the built in; don't override that
def sum(lst):  
    ret = 0
    for item in lst;
        ret += item
    return ret
```

or, if you like functional programming:

```
def sum(lst):
    return reduce(lambda acc, i: acc + i, lst, 0)
```

or even:

```
import operator

def sum(lst):
    return reduce(operator.add, lst, 0)
```

you can even make it work on non-numeric inputs, which the built-in `sum()` cannot do (because it's implemented as efficient C code), but this really goes into the category of over-engineering:

```
def sum(lst, initial=None):
    if initial is None:
        initial = type(lst[0])() if lst else None
    return reduce(lambda acc, i: acc + i, lst, initial)

>>> sum([1, 2, 3])
6
>>> sum(['hello', 'world'])
'hello world'
>>> sum([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

but since Python lists are untyped, in the case of an empty list, this function will return `None`.

**NOTE:** but, as others have pointed out, this is only useful for learning purposes; in real life, you use the built in `sum()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It's already there, no need to define it:

```
sum([8,5,6,7,5,7])
```